# Remove Transaction using ID and Date range in Redshift SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I want to create a query in redshift that will remove transaction items (Table A) base on its validity date (Table B)

Lets call it table A and Table B

Table A contains all transaction of Items

Table A

```
 Item_Code      Date

 1. I0001      2019-12-01 
 2. I0002      2019-12-02 
 3. I0001      2020-01-01 
 4. I0003      2020-01-01
```

then Table 2 contains Item validity date

Table B

```
Item_Code      Valid_From        Valid_To

 1. I0001      2019-01-01         2019-12-31
 2. I0002      2019-01-01         2019-12-31
 3. I0003      2019-01-01         2019-12-31
```

and my expected output will be

Item_Code     Date

```
 1. I0001         2019-12-01
 2. I0002         2019-12-02
```

Answer (score 0):

THis will give your expected results

```
Select * from TableA a where not exists(select 1 from TableB b on a.Date between b.Valid_From        
 and Valid_To)
```

And once you sure thats what you want, you delete it with

```
delete from TableA a where not exists(select 1 from TableB b on a.Date between b.Valid_From        
 and Valid_To)
```

Comment: OP just needs to make sure this doesnt fail the redshift correlated subquery rules.

Comment: IT should pass the rules as its not included in the list referenced https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_correlated_subqueries.html

Answer (score 0):

I would join both tables and insert the validity as a join condition.
This will delete all invalid items or you can reverse the validity condition to detect which items are invalid

```
SELECT A.ITEM_CODE,A.DATE
FROM Table a
INNER JOIN TABLE B 
ON A.ITEM_CODE=B.ITEM_CODE AND A.DATE=> B.Valid_from AND A.date <= B.Valid_to
```